# Selected item in Rider code completion window, not seen

Tags: rider

In Jetbrain's Rider IDE, selected item in code completion windows not seen because of font color is same as highlight color

[image: Rider code completion]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue seems to be fixed in Rider 2019.1:
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RIDER-24744.
Please, try the latest [EAP](https://www.jetbrains.com/rider/eap/)